# Displaying category menus on archives category pages and single product pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, product

My WooCommerce shop has two main categories:

```
cat1
- subcat1
- subcat2
```

and

```
cat2
- subcatA
- subcatB
```

I've made menus of these two branches and they are displayed on category
pages. For easier navigation, I also want to show them **on single product pages**.

My code *(located in woocommerce.php)* is:

```
<?php 
if ( is_tax( 'product_cat', array(14,18,19,20,21,22,23,24)) OR is_single() ) {
   wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'cat1' ) ); 
   }
   elseif ( is_tax( 'product_cat', array(15,16,17,20)) OR is_single() ) {
   wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'cat2' ) ); 
   }
?>
```

This works for the category pages but **not for the single product pages**.

How can I assign all the single products of cat1 and cat2 and display
the assigned menu?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conditional tag [**`is_tax()`**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_tax) checks if a **custom taxonomy archive page is being displayed**. So as you see is not appropriated for single product pages.

You should use [**`has_term()`**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term) conditional function, that will work in a similar way for your single product pages.

So your code is going to be:

```
<?php

$cats1 = array(14,18,19,20,21,22,23,24);
$cats2 = array(15,16,17,20);
$tax = 'product_cat';

if ( is_tax( $tax, $cats1 ) || has_term( $cats1, $tax ) )
   wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'cat1' ) ); 
elseif ( is_tax( $tax, $cats2 ) || has_term( $cats2, $tax ) )
   wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'cat2' ) ); 

?>
```

This should work as you expect for single product pages and archives pages .

Comment: Hi LoicTheActec – works perfect. Thank you for pointing out this logic.